# Why does << 0 remove the decimal portion of a number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, bitwise-operators

When you have a floating-point number, say 10.1, and you utilize the zero fill left shift operator (<<) in JavaScript, it returns just the integer portion of the number, say 10 for the example.

Here's some source code showing what I mean:

```js
var num1 = 958.51243

console.log(num1) // 958.51243
console.log(num1 << 0) // 958
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: because of the specs.

Comment: Does the sun rise because "gravity" also?

Comment: come on. ecma-262 is a standard. the language follows the standard. why ... is always a question of the standard.

Comment: From the standard: *The result is a signed 32-bit integer.*. And here's the standard which wasn't hard to find: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

> The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in two's complement format, except for zero-fill right shift which results in an unsigned 32-bit integer.

So the numbers will be converted to integers before the operation is performed.

For left shift, it's described in the official specification [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-leftShift):

> 6.1.6.1.9 **Number::leftShift ( x, y )**
>
> 1. Let lnum be ! ToInt32(x).
> 2. Let rnum be ! ToUint32(y).
> 3. (...perform operation...)

Where [ToInt32](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toint32) does:

> The abstract operation ToInt32 converts argument to one of 2^32 **integer values** in the range -2^31 through 2^31 - 1, inclusive.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the descriptive answer!

Comment: I cant think of any reason why i would want to bitwise shift a floating point number

Comment: To convert it to an integer.